# Why does the table not end after the last column?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a simple table but the last column is overflowing without border even though the content is not in excess. I'm relatively new to latex so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I used the following code and I've also attached a picture of the output.

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|l|l|p{1.2cm}|p{1cm}|l|l
|l|l|l|l|l|l}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{Paper}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Year}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Methodology}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Modality}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Automatic}}}       
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Supervision}}}  
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Acc.}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Precision}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Sensitivity}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Specificity}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{DS*}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{HS*}}} 
\tabularnewline \hline
[27] &  2022 &  BiTr-Unet & T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR &   semi & supervised & 95\% &   - &    - & - & 0.96 &  9.1647 \\      
 \hline
[28] &  2021 &  LBTS-Net &  T1, T2, FLAIR & semi &  supervised &    98.11\% &    - &    - & - & 91\% &  -                       
\tabularnewline \hline
[29] &  2019 &  stacked sparse auto encoder &   T1, T2 &    automatic & unsupervised &  0.96 &  -  &    0.93 &  1 & 0.96 &  - 
\tabularnewline \hline
[30] &  2020 &  hybrid deep auto encoder &  T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR & automatic &   unsupervised &  98.50\% & 0.96 &    0.96 &  0.9954  & - &   - 
\tabularnewline \hline
[31]    &2020&  MM-GAN& T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR&    semi&   unsupervised&   -   &-  &-& -   &0.6903&    -       
\tabularnewline \hline
[32]&   2021&   DD-GAN  &T1 ,T2w ,T1c , FLAIR   &semi&  unsupervised    &-& 0.735   &0.613  &-  &0.619& -
\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: you end `l|l}` with no final `|`

Comment: `{tabular*}{\textwidth}` means that the table will go up to the full `\textwidth`. Usually is should be combined with something like this (in your case) `{|l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|p{1.2cm}|p{1cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}` to tell it to extend not only the lines but the column separation space too. I think it should be enough in your case.

Comment: @koleygr this resolved my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

- Mostly of topic, since your problem is solved by comment, however, you may be interest to see another way to write your table.
- With use of `tblr` of `tabularray` package your table code can be -- to my opinion of course -- more concise and clear:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep = 4pt,
             colspec = {c l  X[1.3,l,m] 
                        *{3}{X[0.8,l, m, cmd=\hspace{0pt}]}
                             X[0.7,l, m, cmd=\hspace{0pt}] 
                        *{3}{X[0.6,l, m, cmd=\hspace{0pt}]}
                        *{2}{Q[l]} },
             row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape, c}
             }

Paper
    &   Year
        &   Methodology
            &   Modality
                &   Automatic
                    &   Supervision
                        &   Acc.
                            &   Preci\-sion
                                &   Sensi\-tivity
                                    &   Speci\-ficity
                                        &   DS*
                                            &   HS*     \\
{[27]} 
    &  2022
        &   BiTr-Unet
            &   T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR
                &   semi
                    &   supervised
                        &   \qty{95}{\%}
                            & - & - & - &   0.96
                                            &   9.1647  \\
{[28]} 
    &  2021
        &   LBTS-Net
            &   T1, T2, FLAIR
                &   semi
                    &   supervised
                        &   \qty{98.11}{\%}
                            & - & - & - &   \qty{91}{\%}
                                            &  -            \\
{[29]} 
    &  2019
        &   stacked sparse auto encoder
            &   T1, T2
                &   automatic
                    &   unsupervised
                        &   0.96
                            & - & 0.93
                                & 1 & 0.96
                                        &  -            \\
{[30]}
    &  2020
        &   hybrid deep auto encoder
            &   T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR
                &   automatic
                    &   unsupervised
                        &  \qty{98.50}{\%}
                            &   0.96
                                &   0.96
                                    &   0.9954
                                        & - & -         \\
{[31]}    
    &  2020
        &   MM-GAN& T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR
            &   semi
                &   unsupervised
                    & - & - & - & - &   0.6903
                                        &  -            \\
{[32]}
    &  2021
        &   DD-GAN
            &   semi
                &   unsupervised
                    & - &   0.735
                            &   0.613
                                & - &   0.619
                                        &  -            \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, the columns definition looks a lot neater. Could you also explain what's happening in the colspec parameter? Thanks!

Comment: @RyuFeng, the best explanation you can find in package documentation ;-)!.  In colspec are used `c` and ` l` are column tape for centering and left align  column contents, the same as at `tabular` table,  in the ` X[1.3,l,m] `  koeficient `1,3` is ratio of `X` column width, `c` and  `m` define horizontal and vertical align of cells contents.  Command `\cmd` in other columns add zero space, by which is enabled hyphenation of the first word in cell's text. BTW, if answer solve your šproblem)s) you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer.